# Can you use $(this) on an jquery ajax finish function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request, return

Right now i am trying to use $(this).insertFUnctionNameHere() when i get the data back from my ajax post request. I tried to do some tests such as $(this).parent().hide(); $(this).slideUp(); to see where it was selecting but it seems that it is selecting nothing? Is this normal or is there a way for me to have $(this) actually be selecting something.

Here is my code.

```
/*
         * This is the ajax
         */
        $(".reply").on( "submit" , function(){
        // Intercept the form submission
        var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data
        // Post data to your PHP processing script
        $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
            // Act upon the data returned, setting it to .success <div>
            $(this).children().slideUp();
            $(this).children('.success').prepend(data);
            $('.hidden').hide();
        });
        return false;
        });
        /*
         * End ajax
         */
```

Also the link to my website i am using it on is [HERE (readysetfail.com)](http://readysetfail.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're determined to use $(this), but if not I would save the jQuery object referring to the form (retrieved by using $(this) in the event handler) in a variable and use that in the finish function, like so:

```
$(".reply").on( "submit" , function(){
// Intercept the form submission
var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data
var theForm = $(this);
// Post data to your PHP processing script
$.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
    // Act upon the data returned, setting it to .success <div>
    theForm.children().slideUp();
    theForm.children('.success').prepend(data);
    $('.hidden').hide();
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: This also worked! Same idea as the first response but it works! Awesome! I appreciate it tons!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".reply").on( "submit" , function(){
    var reply = $(this);
    ...
    $.post( "/comment.php", formdata, function( data ) {
        reply.children().slideUp();
        reply.children('.success').prepend(data);
        ...
    });
    ...
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!! AHHHH THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been pulling my hair for days as to how to solve this! Thank you so much!